# Comparing dictionaries/lists

Tags: python, list

I am having trouble with a task I need to complete and it's about comparing and printing the similarities of two different lists that have I have been given.
The problem is that when i run it, an error occurs and it says:
**dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 7; 2 is required**

**english.txt reads:**
circle
table
year
competition
**french.txt reads:**
bien
competition
merci
air
table

Here is my code:

```
a = open('english.txt').readlines()
b = open('french.txt').readlines()
a2 = dict(b)
b2 = dict(a)
result = a2.intersection(b2)
print(a2, b2)
```

Comment: what does `a` contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using dictionaries when you need to use lists.

Dictionaries have this structure: {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}

Lists have this structure: ["value1", "value2"]

The error is telling it was specting a 2 value sequence (key and value) but it recieved a 7 value sequence ("circle\n"). This is what python is reading.

```
#In english.txt

circle\n
table\n
year\n
competition
```

Same thing in the other file.

```
#In french.txt

bien\n
competition\n
merci\n
air\n
table
```

You need to replace dict for list and remove the end of line character

```
#This function removes \n character
def processLine(line):
  return line.replace('\n', '')

a = open('english.txt').readlines()          #Read english.txt
e = list([processLine(line) for line in a])  #Create a list where every line in the file is processed
#e = ['circle', 'table', 'year', 'competition']

b = open('french.txt').readlines()           #Read french.txt
f = list([processLine(line) for line in b])  #Create a list where every line in the file is processed
#f = ['bien', 'competition', 'merci', 'air', 'table']

intersection = list(set(e) & set(f))
#intersection = ['table', 'competition']
```

Comment: then how do i print it as table (next line) competition

Comment: for i in intersection: print(i)

Answer (score 0):

I think, for a `dict` data structure you need to pass two values; one for the `key` and other for the `value` that's associated with the key.

For example:

```py
d = {'a':'apple', 'b':'banana'}
```

Edit:
if `a` and `b` are list of words then,

```py
a = "circle table year competition".split()
b = "bien competition merci air table".split()
com_words = list(set(a) & set(b))
```

Comment: I think you're right, but how would I compare the lists still?